# I was trying to convert from string to int. Input was not in correct format is showing

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, code-behind

I was trying to convert from string to int for calculation purpose. What I have is a total_amount in double and unit_quantity in string format. I want to change Unit_quantity string to int. both values are taken from database and total_amount have datatype float and unit_quantity have datatype string.

I have tried normal int.parse option and it's not working.

```
        double UnitAmt = double.Parse(TextboxunitAmt.Text);
        string UnitQty = TextboxunitQty.Text.ToString();

        int Qty = int.Parse(UnitQty);
        double GrandTotal = UnitAmt * Qty;

        TextboxCostPrice.Text = GrandTotal.ToString();
```

The expected result is the correct calculation. But What I get is an error like "Input was not in a correct format"

Comment: `UnitQty` or `TextboxunitAmt.Text` is not a valid number.

Comment: probably depending on your regional settings... if you expect a dot as decimal, you should pass the invariant culture : Double.Parse("10", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: As @BlueEyedBehemoth pointed, either `UnitQty` or `TextboxunitAmt.Text` is not a valid number, you should use `Double.TryParse` / `Int32.TryParse` since it comes from a control and the user may put an invalid value.

Comment: @TonyMkenu, What`s the necessity to post this here?

Comment: Because people are trying to help you, they answer your question ... but then you do not say anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially you have to see what input you're passing into your parse function.

Try something like the following to see a little more of what's going on.

```
    // Lets try parsing some random strings into doubles.
    // Each one with varying cases.
    string[] testStrings = new string[]{"$32.43", "342", "1,332", "0.93", "123,432.34", "boat"};
    foreach (string ts in testStrings)
    {
        double newValue;
        if (double.TryParse(ts, out newValue))
        {
            // for WPF, you can use a MessageBox or Debug.WriteLine
            Console.WriteLine("We were able to successfully convert '" + ts + "' to a double! Here's what we got: " + newValue);
        }
        else
        {
            // for WPF, you can use a MessageBox or Debug.WriteLine
            Console.WriteLine("We were unable to convert '" + ts + "' to a double");
        }
    }
```

Here's the output you should see:

```
We were unable to convert '$32.43' to a double
We were able to successfully convert '342' to a double! Here's what we got: 342
We were able to successfully convert '1,332' to a double! Here's what we got: 1332
We were able to successfully convert '0.93' to a double! Here's what we got: 0.93
We were able to successfully convert '123,432.34' to a double! Here's what we got: 123432.34
We were unable to convert 'boat' to a double
```

Answer (score -4):

Try this code :

```
double UnitAmt = double.Parse(TextboxunitAmt.Text);
string UnitQty = TextboxunitQty.Text.ToString();

int Qty = int.Parse(UnitQty);
double GrandTotal = Convert.ToDouble(UnitAmt) * Convert.ToDouble(Qty);

TextboxCostPrice.Text = GrandTotal.ToString();
```

Comment: The problem is in the int.Parse method, plus the double conversion is automagic when you multiple double and int.